# Installing a Django App RPM with python 2.7 on RHEL

Tags: django, python-2.7, rpmbuild

Since RHEL comes with python 2.6, I use chef to install python 2.7 under /usr/local/bin (pretty standard stuff).

Up until now we were deploying a django app with fabric and a remote git pull call.  I'm trying to install it via an RPM which is a bit cleaner IMO.

I've put together a setup.py script and corresponding MANIFEST.in to combine packages, html and static files.  I use `python setup.py bdist_rpm` and all is good so far.

Upon examining the spec file generated under `<project_root>/build/SPECS/App.spec`, the install directive has

```
%install
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed -O1 - root=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT --record=INSTALLED_FILES
```

Is there any way I can change the setup.py file so that the SPEC is generated as

```
%install
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed -O1 --root=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT --record=INSTALLED_FILES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by looking at the Django repo.  In it there the file `setup.cfg`

```
[bdist_rpm]
doc_files = docs extras AUTHORS INSTALL LICENSE README.rst
install-script = scripts/rpm-install.sh
```

In the `rpm-install.sh` script there is:

```
# This is what dist.py normally does.
%{__python} setup.py install --root=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT} --record="INSTALLED_FILES"
```

So I replaced `%{__python}` with /usr/local/bin/python2.7 and it works!